# How to re-save a password in Google Chrome?

Tags: passwords

So, I have a password I need. I deleted it before. I thought I would remember, but I don't. I tried my password that I used to have, but it doesn't work. I don't know if I changed it and forgot! How do I re-save that password?! I need it! A LOT. I was crying a lot for a while...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Chrome issue. You deleted the password, so go back to the originating site, enter your userid (nominally email address) and use the Forgot Password function